# Reference request: Chern slopes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, chern-classes

Let $M$ be a compact Kähler surface. The Chern slope is defined to be $$c_1^2/c_2,$$ where $c_1,c_2$ are the first and second Chern classes of $M$.

The classic *Compact complex surfaces* book by Barth-Hulek-Peters-Van de Ven, treats the "geography problem" on page 290 in some detail. But, the number of explicit examples exhibited there is effectively negligible (this could be merely, and likely is, a symptom of my lack of understanding). Can someone direct me to a more explicit treatment of the geography problem, or better, direct me to a reference which answers the following:

> Which complex surfaces have Chern slope in the interval $[1/3,1[$?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://superficie.info/

Comment: @YangMills: That link is so good that it could be posted as an answer.

Comment: https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2015/182-1/p06

Comment: @YangMills Thank you so much, this is incredible!